# How to position TextBlock in Canvas after window resize?

Tags: wpf, animation, resize, dependency-properties, window-resize

I have a `TextBlock` which I move within a `Canvas` via `DoubleAnimation()`. On the enclosing Window `SizeChanged` event, I am able to properly resize the `TextBlock.FontSize` and inner `Canvas`, but I am having problems getting the position of the `TextBlock` correctly within the `Canvas`. (I was trying to do some form of `Canvas.SetTop(NameQueueTextBlock, <newVal>)` but that didn't work.)

```
<Canvas Grid.Column="1" ClipToBounds="True">
    <Canvas Name="NameQueueCanvas" ClipToBounds="True" Height="79" Width="309">
        <TextBlock Canvas.Top="0" Name="NameQueueTextBlock" FontSize="19" Text="&#10;"/>
    </Canvas>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: Changing the font size sounds like you want to visually scale the whole content of your window. You may just put everything in a `Viewbox`.

Comment: @Clemens - tried that. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm gonna guess your `DoubleAnimation` is the culprit.

If it hold's the end value(which is the default) of `Canvas.Top` while moving the `TextBlock` any future updates of `Canvas.Top` according to the WPF priority system will "appear" to be ignored.

**Solution:**

switch

```
Canvas.SetTop(NameQueueTextBlock, /*newVal*/);
```

with

```
NameQueueTextBlock.BeginAnimation(Canvas.TopProperty, null);
Canvas.SetTop(NameQueueTextBlock, /*newVal*/);
```

and you should be sorted.

**Alternate approach:**

Assuming your `Storyboard` is called `sb`, Just before calling `sb.Begin();`

add something like:

```
sb.Completed += (o, args) => {
  var finalVal = Canvas.GetTop(NameQueueTextBlock);
  NameQueueTextBlock.BeginAnimation(Canvas.TopProperty, null);
  Canvas.SetTop(NameQueueTextBlock, finalVal);
};
```

I'd prefer this as it then allows you to not keep track of which code-fragment might potentially change the `Canvas.Top` on the `TextBlock` first and reset the property with a `null` animation before-hand.

Comment: This seems to be the right thing to do.  However, I am not figuring out the correct formula for `/*newVal*/`  Any suggestions as to what I should be basing that on?

Comment: @Conrad what do you mean by formula for `newVal`? I don't know about your requirements for that. You'd need to explain exactly what you expect. If you want the `TextBlock` to maintain relative positions to the `Canvas` as it had before the size change, you could calculate the `Left` and `Top` as percentage of total old canvas width and then for the same % calculate with new canvas width what should be the offsets and apply it. I'm with @Clemens tho, this just sounds more and more like you should use a `ViewBox`

Comment: I just saw your comments, and I had already figured it out - you are correct that I need `finalVal * e.NewSize.Height / e.PreviousSize.Height` for the 2nd param of `SetTop`.  (As I mentioned above, I tried inserting a `ViewBox` in several places and it never gave the desired results.  In any case, it is all working now.)